# Hide links in previous td contain span class inactive css/js

Tags: javascript, css

I currently have a table in my project and I'm facing a challenge related to hiding some href links. Specifically, I want to implement a functionality where links should be hidden if the corresponding table cell (td) contains the "inactive" class inside a span element.

If you could provide insights or guidance on how to achieve this, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for your assistance!

Example

```
<table class="tg">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-0lax">ID</th>
    <th class="tg-0lax">NAME</th>
    <th class="tg-0lax">VIEW</th>
    <th class="tg-0lax">EDIT</th>
    <th class="tg-0pky">STATUS</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">Example1</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"><a href="#"></a></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"><a href="#"></a></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"><span class="active"><a href="#"></a></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">2</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">Example2</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"><a href="#"></a></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"><a href="#"></a></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"><span class="active"><a href="#"></a></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">3</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">Example3</td>
     <td class="tg-0lax"><a href="#"></a></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"><a href="#"></a></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"><span class="inactive"><a href="#"></a></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">4</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">Example4</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"><a href="#"></a></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"><a href="#"></a></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"><span class="inactive"><a href="#"></a></span></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I would like to achieve this via CSS if possible.

```
<table class="tg">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-0lax">ID</th>
    <th class="tg-0lax">NAME</th>
    <th class="tg-0lax">VIEW</th>
    <th class="tg-0lax">EDIT</th>
    <th class="tg-0pky">STATUS</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">1</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">Example1</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"><a href="#"></a></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"><a href="#"></a></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"><span class="active"><a href="#"></a></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">2</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">Example2</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"><a href="#"></a></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"><a href="#"></a></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"><span class="active"><a href="#"></a></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">3</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">Example3</td>
     <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"><span class="inactive"></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">4</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">Example4</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"><span class="inactive"></span></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: the difference is that where the inactive class appears there are no connections from the two previous cells.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do this by selecting the span within the td, with the inactive class:

```css
td span.inactive a{
display:none;
}
```

Comment: and to hide links in previous td?

Comment: Please could you edit your question to include the 'hide links in previous td' requirement as this isn't currently stated there. And is it what you mean?

Comment: @A Haworth, It was not stated in his first question to hide as well the previous td element. And also can't select a previous sibling in css, but with javascript yes

Comment: @Mehdi I 'was asking the questioner to elaborate on their 'and to hide links in previous td>'  comment